# How to Inject an object which is created with Assisted Injection in Guice?

Tags: java, dependency-injection, guice, code-injection, assisted-inject

I'm trying to pass an object which has a runtime variable into an other object. How can I achieve this using Guice? I'm new to dependency injection.

I would like to create several A objects (the number of them is decided at runtime) and that many B objects that uses an A object. But first let's start with one object from both of them.

Thank you for your help.

```
public interface IA {
    String getName();
}

public class A implements IA {
    @Getter
    protected final String name;

    @AssistedInject
    A(@Assisted String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}

public interface IAFactory {
    IA create(String name);
}

public interface IB {
    IA getA();
}

public class B implements IB {  
    @Getter
    protected final IA a;

    //...
    // some more methods and fields
    //...

    @Inject
    B(IA a) {
        this.a = a;
    }
}

public class MyModule extends AbstractModule {
    @Override
    protected void configure() {
        install(new FactoryModuleBuilder()
         .implement(IA.class, A.class)
         .build(IAFactory.class));

        bind(IB.class).to(B.class);
    }
}

public class Main() {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        if(args.size < 1) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("First arg is required");
        }
        String name = args[0];

        Injector injector = Guice.createInjector(new MyModule());
        IB b = injector.getInstance(IB.class);
        System.out.println(b.getA().getName());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are not exactly clear about this. So let me explain a little.

Firstly, you created a Factory which you will use to create instances of `A`. You did that because Guice doesn't know the value of parameter `name`.

Now what you want is to create an instance of `B` which depends on instance of `A`. You are asking Guice to give you an instance of `B` but how will Guice create an instance of `B` without an `A`? You haven't binded any instance of `A`.

So to fix this issue you will either have to create an instance of `B` manually.

The way you can achieve it is by following.

Firstly, you will require a Factory for `B`

```
public interface IBFactory {
    IB create(String name);
}
```

Then you need to make the following changes in your class `B`

```
public class B implements IB {  

    protected final A a;

    @AssistedInject
    public B(@Assisted String name, IAFactory iaFactory) {
        this.a = iaFactory.create(name);
    }
}
```

Now in your `main` method

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    if(args.size < 1) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("First arg is required");
    }
    String name = args[0];

    Injector injector = Guice.createInjector(new MyModule());
    IBFactory ibFactory = injector.getInstance(IBFactory.class);
    IB b = ibFactory.create(name)
    System.out.println(b.getA().getName());
}
```

Also, don't forget to update your configure method and install B factory.

```
protected void configure() {
    install(new FactoryModuleBuilder()
     .implement(IA.class, A.class)
     .build(IAFactory.class));

    install(new FactoryModuleBuilder()
     .implement(IB.class, B.class)
     .build(IBFactory.class));
}
```

**Note**
I am passing `name` in class B. You can update IBFactory to take `IA` as assisted parameter and then first create an instance of `IA` outside using `IAFactory` and pass the instance of `IA` to `IBFactory` to create an instance of `IB`